# how to give innerhtml values to elements inside a cloned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing a search form, for that I need divs dynamically for showing search results.
Now I am trying is,

1. create the html elements.
2. for each result, clone the structure and replace the inner html of appropreate elements with my results.
3. Append the result with the existing results.
   but I dont know how to replace the innerhtml with the results.
   I have created the following code in html,`

---

```
<div id="resultsDiv">
    <div id="webResult">
        <div id="heading"></div>
        <p id="s_item"></p>
        <h5 id="s_description"></h5>
        <span id="s_offer"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for javascript I have crated,

```
templete_element=document.getElementById('resultsDiv');
for(i=0;i<result_count;i++){
    $("#webResult").clone().insertAfter("#webResult");
}
```

For each execution of for loop I need to:

- replace inner html of id 'heading' with `dataArray.root.data.partners[0].item_heading`
- replace inner html of id 's_item' with `dataArray.root.data.partners[0].item_name`
- replace inner html of id 's_description' with `dataArray.root.data.partners[0].item_description`
- replace inner html of id 's_offer with' `dataArray.root.data.partners[0].item_offer`

Please forgive me If my language is bad.
thanku.

Comment: That method is creating duplicate IDs

Comment: Why are you using pure javascript selector (`document.getElementById`) and jquery selector at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid creating elements with duplicate ids on a page, this makes it impossible to reference them as an ID has to be unique. You should change your markup to work with classes instead:

```
<div id="resultsDiv">
    <div class="webResult">
        <div class="heading"></div>
        <p class="s_item"></p>
        <h5 class="s_description"></h5>
        <span class="s_offer"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that you can work with those classes instead:

```
for(i=0;i<result_count;i++){
    var myResult = $(".webResult:first").clone().insertAfter(".webResult:last");
    myResult.find('.heading').html( 'put dynamic data here' );
}
```

I used the first and last modifiers to get the first element as the "template" and append it to the last one created in the loop.